# Python: replace for loop with function

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, for-loop

Can anyone help me to understand how I would create a function with `def whatever()` instead of using a for loop. I'm trying to do thing more Pythonically but don't really understand how to apply a function well instead of a loop. For instance, I have a loop below that works well and gives the output I would like, is there a way to do this with a function?

```
seasons = leaguesFinal['season'].unique()
teams = teamsDF['team_long_name'].unique()
df = []

for i in seasons:
    season = leaguesFinal['season'] == i
    season = leaguesFinal[season]
    for j in teams:
        team_season_wins = season['win'] == j
        team_season_win_record = team_season_wins[team_season_wins].count()
        team_season_loss = season['loss'] == j
        team_season_loss_record = team_season_loss[team_season_loss].count()
        df.append((j, i, team_season_win_record, team_season_loss_record))
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=('Team', 'Seasons', 'Wins', 'Losses'))
```

The output looks as follows:

```
      Team               Seasons    Wins    Losses
0   KRC Genk            2008/2009   15       14
1   Beerschot AC        2008/2009   11       14
2   SV Zulte-Waregem    2008/2009   16       11
3   Sporting Lokeren    2008/2009   13        9
4   KSV Cercle Brugge   2008/2009   14       15
```

Comment: Why should a simple loop be not "pythonical"? You could also write a recurring function, but that is not very readable in this case, where your loop provides excellent understanding of what is going on. This is one of the main goals of Python.

Comment: hmm.. you could use the dataframe progress_apply method to iterate over your dataframe. this would definitely remove one for loop (maybe both depending on how you define your function) as well as improve the speed of execution.

Comment: Another question: I do not get how this code can work in lines 6 and 7. `leaguesFinal['season'] == i` will alway return a boolean value. In the next line you use this boolean value as argument for `__getitem__`. This will lead to a `KeyError` unless you have a key of the given boolean value.

Comment: @SvenKrüger I don't know why it doesn't return the key error? Sorry. And I gues syou're right about the 'pythonical' thing, I'm looking intot this because my instructor says I use loops too much and should try to use functions more

Comment: then he obviously has no idea what he's talking about because loops and functions are completely unrelated! functions just get into the game if you write the same loop over and over again.

Comment: @Cut7er perfect, I'll let him know that ;p

Comment: "Replacing loops with functions" does not make any sense to me (>10 years experience in coding). Even the statement itself does not. The only thing you can do is "hide" the loops within a function, like @vash_the_stampede suggested in his answer. This encapsulation will just lead to a more abstract view on the process, but will not prevent you from using a loop contruct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
def some_loop(something, something_else):
    for i in something:
        season = leaguesFinal['sesaon'] == i
        season = leaguesFinal[season]
        for j in something_else:
            team_season_wins = season['win'] == j
            team_season_win_record = team_season_wins[team_season_wins].count()
            team_season_loss = season['loss'] == j
            team_season_loss_record = team_season_loss[team_season_loss].count()
            df.append((j, i, team_season_win_record, team_season_loss_record))

some_loop(seasons, teams)
```

**Comments**

This is what you are mentioning, creating a function out of the `for` loop although you still have a  `for` loop its in a function that you can use in different areas of your code without re-using the entire code for the loop.

All there is to to is define a function that accepts two variables for this particular loop that would be `def some_loop(something, something_else)`, I used basic naming so you could see clearer whats taking place.

Then you would replace all the instanes of `seasons` and `teams` with those variables.

Now you call your function will replace all occurences of `something` and `something_else` with whatever inputs you send to it.

Also I am not completely sure of the statements that involve `x = y = i` and what this accomplishes or if its even a valid statement?

Comment: Thanks, because I asked for an example of making my loop a function I've made this the accepted answer, although others have explained it's not necessary per this example

Comment: @55thSwiss Glad I could help!

Comment: @vash_the_stampede Maybe Data Frame Object have the method `__eq__` replaced, such that it does not return the truth value of the statement but instead the elements, for which this statement is true.

Answer (score 0):

actually youre mixing stuff up - `functions` just aggregate lines of code and thus make them reproducable without writing everything again, whereas `for-loops` are for iteration purposes.

In your above mentioned example, a function would just contain the `for-loop` and return the resulting dataframe, which you could use then. but it will not change anything or make your code smarter.

Comment: Thanks for the specification